# Instruct CMake's ExternalProject_Add to update only once a day?

Tags: cmake

I'm working on reducing build time for my project. In my top level `CMakeLists.txt` I add several external projects, e.g. `googletest`:

```
ExternalProject_Add(googletest
   PREFIX "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/googletest"
   GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/google/googletest.git
   INSTALL_DIR "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}"
   CMAKE_ARGS "-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}"
   )
```

When I recompile the project, `googletest` also recompiles or at least it takes about 15 second for being processed. I can avoid that by adding `UPDATE_COMMAND ""`. Then goolgetest will not be recompiled and building is about 15s faster.

Ideally googletest would update, if e.g. the local clone wasn't updated for a day. That way I would not need to comment the `UPDATE_COMMAND ""`-line out for getting the latest version.

Is there a way to accomplish this automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to store current date in cache variable and update googletest only if date changed since previous cmake configuration run.

"TODAY" macro used in following script was found on [cmake mailing list archive](https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2009-February/027014.html).

```
macro (TODAY RESULT)
  if (WIN32)
    execute_process(COMMAND "date" "/T" OUTPUT_VARIABLE ${RESULT})
    string(REGEX REPLACE "(..)/(..)/..(..).*" "\\3\\2\\1"
      ${RESULT} ${${RESULT}})
  elseif(UNIX)
    execute_process(COMMAND "date" "+%d/%m/%Y" OUTPUT_VARIABLE ${RESULT})
    string(REGEX REPLACE "(..)/(..)/..(..).*" "\\3\\2\\1"
      ${RESULT} ${${RESULT}})
  else (WIN32)
    message(SEND_ERROR "date not implemented")
    set(${RESULT} 000000)
  endif (WIN32)
endmacro (TODAY)

TODAY(CURRENT_DATE)
message("Current date is: ${CURRENT_DATE}")

if(${PREVIOUS_CURRENT_DATE} AND ${PREVIOUS_CURRENT_DATE} STREQUAL ${CURRENT_DATE})
  message("Sorry. Googletest already updated today.")
else()
  message("Ok. It's first time today!")
  set(PREVIOUS_CURRENT_DATE ${CURRENT_DATE} CACHE INTERNAL "Current date")
  ExternalProject_Add(googletest
    PREFIX "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/googletest"
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/google/googletest.git
    INSTALL_DIR "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}"
    CMAKE_ARGS "-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}"
    )
endif()
```

If build directory is changed or CMakeCache.txt removed, cached date will be lost - googletest will be updated after cmake configuration/build.

Also note that date is compared **only during cmake configuration step**.
So unless cmake configuration is executed explicitly or CMakeLists.txt was modified, date comparison will be skipped.

Comment: great answer! I still think such a function should be provided by CMake. Please open a feature request.

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box this isn't possible. Maybe you can come up with a workaround using `UPDATE_DISCONNECTED`.

Probably it's best to file a feature request for CMake (and share it here). I think your use case is valid.